# iframe cross domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, dns

we have a html page with a iframe in it on our server, the content of that iframe is from another domain. When client side view this html page, they can right click on the iframe to view the sources, but how can we code to access to that code from the outside..

Answer (score 2):

You [can't spy on the data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) that your visitors get from other sites.

If you know the URI they are visiting (which is only possible for the initial page specified by the src attribute (because you decide that that is)), then you can make an HTTP request from your server (the specifics of how you do that depends on the technologies available on  your server). That will get you the content of the page (but not with the user's credentials).